# Selecting a range of days across multiple years

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a problem that involves the `WHERE` clause of my query:

```
...
WHERE distinct_policy.policy_created_date_time between '2023-03-01' and '2023-03-11'
```

The column "*policy_created_date_time*" is a timestamp without time zone. I want to select only ten days (first March - tenth March), but in any year (not just in 2023).

Is there any simple way to do it, because sql doesn't allow me just to delete the year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to check on months and days, by extracting directly those parts, using [`EXTRACT`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date-functions/postgresql-extract/).

```
...
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM distinct_policy.policy_created_date_time) = 3 
  AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM distinct_policy.policy_created_date_time) BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Comment: thank you! But still have one problem. It doesn't see xx-03-01 (First March) for some reason, any ideas why?

Comment: Can you craft a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)?

Comment: [BETWEEN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html) has inclusive endpoints so  it would be `BETWEEN 1 AND 10`.

Comment: @DmitryLaevskih, are you sure that `policy_created_date_time` is `timestamp` not a`timestamptz` field?

Answer (score 0):

You can use generate_series and a range data type to solve this issue. You now can also use an (existing) index on your column.

This example takes the next 100 years, you could take a different start or end.

```
WITH target AS (
    SELECT  tsrange(t::date,    t::date + 10, '[]') r
    FROM    generate_series('2023-03-01'::timestamp, '2023-03-01'::timestamp + INTERVAL '100 years', INTERVAL '1 year' ) g(t)
)
SELECT t.*
FROM t -- your table
  JOIN target ON r @> policy_created_date_time;
```